# Generalization of the `Functor` class to become a `MultiFunctor`?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I am learning from the "[Free Applicative Functors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.0749.pdf)". Surely, the question I am going to ask is kind of aside with respect to main idea of the paper, but still...

...on the page 6 there is an attempt to generalize `Functor` to `MultiFunctor`:

```
class Functor f ⇒ MultiFunctor f where
    fmap0 :: a → f a
    fmap1 :: (a → b) → f a → f b
    fmap1 = fmap
    fmap2 :: (a → b → c) → f a → f b → f c
    ...
```

I can not see how this definition is justified from the category theory's viewpoint: `fmap2` seems to be just a bifunctor, i.e. a functor defined on a [product category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category). By definition, product category is given by all possible ordered pairs of objects and morphisms are pairs as well, hence: `fmap2 :: (a -> a', b -> b') -> (f a, f b) -> (f a', f b')` looks and feels like more appropriate signature.

I can understand the way of thinking standing behing the `(a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c` choice: it is just the most obvious way to take known `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` signature and force it to work with binary functions, rather then unary. But is`MultiFunctor` (given by the definition above) actually a bi-/multifunctor in the sense that category theory expects it to be?

P.S. The reason why I am curious is that it seems like one **can't** get to the `Applicative` by generalizing `Functor`, though paper states that one can.

Comment: `fmap2 :: (a -> a', b -> b') -> (f a, f b) -> (f a', f b')` can be a nice operation, but this is directly derivable from the standard functor class as `fmap2 (f,g) (x,y) = (fmap f x, fmap g y)`, so there would be no need to have another typeclass. Instead, the original `fmap2 :: (a → b → c) → f a → f b → f c` can not be derived, so it is a real extension (an additional requirement on `f`).

Comment: @chi, that's the point of my question: is `(a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c` really a generalization of `Functor` to be a theoretic `Bifunctor`, or just a useful extension from programming point of view, which has nothing to do with true bifunctor? Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: I'd say it has nothing to do with bifunctors. That extension, I guess, can be formalized nicely in category theory, and not only in programming, but it's not a bifunctor. To me, "applicative" is an additional requirement on a (unary, covariant) functor between cartesian closed categories, where there's a morphism from `F(b^a)` to `(F b)^(F a)` satisfying a bunch of laws.

Comment: @chi, exactly, see the answer beneath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the category theory angle you are taking is wrong. There is a Bifunctor class (with a map of type `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> f a c -> f b d`) but that is not what this generalisation is. If one uncurries some functions then the signature of `fmap2` looks like:

```
fmap2 :: ((a,b) -> c) -> (f a, f b) -> f c
```

And by considering `fmap2 id`, we see that what we are implementing is not a bifunctor but a cartesian functor (i.e. a monoidal functor between cartesian categories), with `fmap2 id :: (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)` being the natural transformation:

[image: \mu_{x,y} : F(x) \otimes F(y) \to F(x \otimes y)]

One can then get an applicative from this `Multifunctor` generalisation. Just change `pure` for `fmap0` and `(<*>)` for `fmap2 ($)`.

Comment: Sure, if you take a moment to go throught page 6, paper states that `fmap2` is generalization of `Functor` to `Multifunctor`. That's why I anchored to the bifunctor. Thank's for reply!

Comment: Note however that the mere addition of `fmap2` is not sufficient to make a (Haskell) applicative as one also needs a way to construct elements of type `f a`, e.g. `fmap0` or something of type `f ()` that behaves in a sensible way.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the obvious: `fmap0` is pure.

Here's one you made a mistake on: `fmap2` is `liftA2`.

(`bimap` is very different - `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> f a b -> f c d`)

And if you go back to the [definition of `Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative), you see that it has a default implementation of `(<*>)`, which is `liftA2 id`, which allows you to define it in terms of pure and either `liftA2` or `(<*>)`.

So yes, that class is equivalent to `Applicative`.

Comment: `(a -> b, c -> d) -> f (a, b) -> f (c, d)` is not very different from what I've mentioned. It is actually the same, as long as you keep in mind that `f a b` is just a pair of objects `f (a, b)` and `(a -> b, c -> d)` is an **uncurried** version, which is isomorphic to the curried one, given by your example.