# About mapping on the eventual result of a multi-argument function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, currying, partial-application

I known that `r -> a` is a `Functor` in `a`, and that `fmap = (.)` for it.

This means that when I do `fmap f g`, with `g :: r -> a`, `f` is applied to the result of `g` as soon as the latter is fed with a value of type `r`. However, if `a` is a function type, e.g. a unary function `b -> c`, then there's a difference between applying `f` to that function (which is what happens in reality) and applying `f` to the eventual result of `g` (which could be desirable in some cases; couldn't it?).

How do I map on the eventual result of `g`? In this case of `g :: r -> b -> c` it seems easy, I can just `uncurry $ fmap f $ curry g`. But what if also `c` is a function type?

Or, in other words, how do I map on the final result of multi-variable function? Is the `curry`/`uncurry` trick necessary/doable in general?

(Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167529/generalization-of-the-functor-class-to-become-a-multifunctor).)

As it's apparent from comments/answers, I have not realized I was essentially asking the same question I've already asked some days ago. Probably it was not apparent to me because of *how* I got here. Essentially, what led me to ask this question is another one storming in my head:

*If I can use `liftA2 (&&)`, `liftA2 (||)`, and similar to combine unary predicates, how do I combine binary predicates?* To answer to this, I played around a bit in GHCi, and came up with this

```hs
liftIntoBinaryFunc p = \q r -> curry $ (liftA2 p) (uncurry q) (uncurry r)
```

which would allow doing something like this:

```hs
-- some binary predicate
distanceLE3 x y = 3 >= abs (x - y)
sameSign x y = ((==) `on` signum) x y

-- function to lift into binary functions
liftIntoBinaryFunc p = \q r -> curry $ (liftA2 p) (uncurry q) (uncurry r)

-- lifting && into binary functions to Bool
and' = liftIntoBinaryFunc (&&)

-- combining 
pred = distance3 `and'` sameSign

-- using
p 3 18   -- False
p 3 1    -- True
p 3 (-1) -- False
```

However, this question too generalizes to *how do I combine predicates of arbitrary (though common) arity?*, and probably the answer is the same.

Comment: "*But what if also `c` is a function type?*" - then it's another level more, and a different `fmap` function. There is no way to have a generic function that maps over the "eventual result" of a function with arbitrarily many parameters.

Comment: for binary functions it's `(fmap . fmap)`. and if it's arbitrary number, you've already asked about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883973/about-mapping-thorught-several-nested-functorial-levels) recently.

Comment: Wow. @WillNess, I didn't realize it was exactly the same problem :D Probably because I got to this formulation of the question from a totally different angle. Essentially what led me to ask this question is another one storming in my head: _If I can `liftA2` `&&`, `||` and others to combine unary predicates, how do I combine binary predicates?_ Probably this would be a 3rd shape to the same actual question, wouldn't it? I will add this in the question, which will probably make me look less stupid too.

Comment: The answer is the same: apply `liftA2` multiple times.

Comment: `(liftA2 . liftA2) (&&) ((>=).(+10)) (<=) 9 10`.

Comment: Yeah, I got there myself, then I thought about combining n-ary predicates, finally noticed it all boiled down to mapping to the final result of a function, and so I asked the present question, failing in understanding it was my own older question. I'm just a bit dumb sometimes.

Comment: @Enlico Try to manually unify `(fmap . fmap)` (or better `(.) . (.)` for the sake of simplicity) to get a better understanding how this works.

Comment: (Ahah, the boobs operator, right?) @scriptum, I still have to understand what "unify" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r -> b -> c` is `r -> (b -> c)` and so `(fmap . fmap) (f :: c -> d) (g :: r -> b -> c) :: r -> b -> d`:

```
> foo :: (c -> d) -> (r -> (b -> c)) -> r -> (b -> d) ;
  foo = fmap . fmap

foo :: (c -> d) -> (r -> b -> c) -> r -> b -> d

> bar :: (c -> d) -> (r -> (b -> (t -> c))) -> r -> (b -> (t -> d)) ;
  bar = fmap . fmap . fmap

bar :: (c -> d) -> (r -> b -> t -> c) -> r -> b -> t -> d
```

But you will have to know how many nested levels are there, to compose the `fmaps` accordingly, or use approaches from your other [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883973/about-mapping-thorught-several-nested-functorial-levels).

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to accept *n* arguments and then apply `f`, you may call `fmap` *n* times. So, if `g :: r -> b -> c`, then

```
(fmap . fmap) f g
```

will apply `f` to the value of type `c` that results from applying `g` to two arguments, while if `h :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g`, then

```
   a      b      c      d      e      f
(fmap . fmap . fmap . fmap . fmap . fmap) f h
```

will apply `f` to the value of type `g` that results from applying `h` to 6 arguments.